# How to calculate the amount of change on gate-source voltage needed in this two stage comparator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos

This is a homework question.

Below schematic of a two stage comparator is given.

I understand that \$I_5=2*I_4\$ and \$I_6\$ and \$I_7\$ can be written in terms of \$I_4\$.

It is given that in the below circuit, \$I_6>I_7\$. How much change is needed on \$V_{GS6}\$ is solved as:

\$\Delta V_{GS6}=\dfrac{\sqrt I_6 - \sqrt I_7}{\sqrt {\dfrac{K_6'}{2}*\dfrac{W_6}{L_6}}}\$

How is this equation obtained?

[image]

Comment: Also, similar example could be found in page 9 of [this](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/ee508/GAS_book/chap6e.pdf) PDF. However, it didn't explain the equation, it just used it.

Comment: Isn't it true that I6 always equals I7 (we are assuming no current flow through Vo, right)? It seems like the equation might be a way to refine an initial guess that isn't quite right, perhaps.

Comment: @Justin I have found the answer to my question. I will post an answer soon. It assumes that in this design case, it is not true that \$I_6=I_7\$ and the \$V_{GS}\$ voltage of M6 is modified so that \$I_6=I_7\$. My lecturer's notes does not show how the amount of change needed for the \$V_{GS6}\$ is found, and I was asking this. Also, probably there is a current flowing through Vo, and Vn=Vp=0, however these are not specified clearly, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In the current conditions, \$I_7\$ is not equal to \$I_6\$. Let's write the equation for \$I_6\$:

\$I_6=\dfrac{1}{2}*K_6*\dfrac{W_6}{L_6}*(V_{GS6}-V_T)^2\$

\$V_{GS6}=\sqrt{I_6*\dfrac{2}{K_6}*\dfrac{L_6}{W_6}}+V_T\$

When we change \$V_{GS6}\$, \$I_7\$ will be equal to \$I_6\$.

\$I_7=I_6=\dfrac{1}{2}*K_6*\dfrac{W_6}{L_6}*(V_{GS6}'-V_T)^2\$

\$V_{GS6}'=\sqrt{I_7*\dfrac{2}{K_6}*\dfrac{L_6}{W_6}}+V_T\$

\$\Delta V_{GS6}\$ is the difference of the two conditions and can be written as:

\$\Delta V_{GS6} = |V_{GS6} - V_{GS6}'|\$

\$\Delta V_{GS6} = \sqrt{I_6*\dfrac{2}{K_6}*\dfrac{L_6}{W_6}}+V_T - \left(  \sqrt{I_7*\dfrac{2}{K_6}*\dfrac{L_6}{W_6}}+V_T\right )\$

\$\Delta V_{GS6} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{K_6}*\dfrac{L_6}{W_6}}*\left(\sqrt{I_6}-\sqrt{I_7}\right)\$

This result is the same thing as the equation you have given:

\$\Delta V_{GS6}=\dfrac{\sqrt{I_6} - \sqrt{I_7}}{\sqrt {\dfrac{K_6'}{2}*\dfrac{W_6}{L_6}}}\$